# The event can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= error

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Hi so am trying to make this event change when the state is updated for some reason it's not allowing me to compile it's giving the error:

```
The event 'Entity.StateChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
```

I don't know what's wrong it seems right i tried google it did not help

```
public Entity.State state
{
    get
    {
        return this._state;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this._state != value)
        {
            this._state = value;
            this.OnStateChanged();
        }
    }
}

protected virtual void OnStateChanged()
{
    if (this.StateChanged != null)
    {
        this.StateChanged();
    }
}

public event Action StateChanged
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    add
    {
        this.StateChanged += value;
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    remove
    {
        this.StateChanged -= value;
    }
}
```

Thank you guy's for your time and help!

Comment: I don't know about the given error, but writing `this.StateChanged += value` in the add handler of `StateChanged` sounds like a good way to get a Stack Overflow

Comment: Why are you adding custom add/remove handlers in the first place?

Comment: Is there a way to fix the Stack Overflow problem, Also i am testing the event action i'm learning so sorry!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-event- can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496799/event-can-only-appear-on-the-left-hand-side-of-or)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one implements [custom events accessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713648.aspx), then he has to provide a **backing delegate field** that will be used to store added callbacks:

```
protected virtual void OnStateChanged()
{
    var stateChanged = this._stateChanged;
    if (stateChanged == null)
        return;

    stateChanged();
}

private Action _stateChanged;

public event Action StateChanged
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    add
    {
        this._stateChanged += value;
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    remove
    {
        this._stateChanged -= value;
    }
}
```

---

But why does it work with standard/non-custom events like `public event Action StateChanged;`?

Because compiler automatically generates a backing field for that event and you can get get it with `var action = this.StateChanged;`, but you should know that **[events are not fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367137/events-arent-fields-i-dont-get-it)** - they are a pair of methods - `add, remove`. It is the compiler that contextually accesses event's autogenerated **backing field** when you do `var action = this.StateChanged;`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and explanation helps alot!